# Compile error when using template aliases, inheriting template and using a "template parent's" types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, gcc4.7, template-aliases

I have a data container which has following requirements:

- Be fast: Hence templates and not normal inheritance
- Use different implementations
- Be able to extend those implementations with more methods
- Data is specified via template argument and needs to be able to save pointers to data container items

The solution I have come up with is as follows:

```
    template<typename T, template<typename> class container_t>
class data_c
{
public:
    typedef data_c<T, container_t> value_type;
    typedef typename container_t<value_type>::ref container_ref;

    container_ref link;
    T c;
};

template<typename T>
class storage_container_impl
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef storage_container_impl<T>* ref;
    T data;
};

template<typename _impl>
class storage_container : public _impl
{
public:
    typedef typename _impl::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename _impl::ref ref;
};

template<typename T>
using impl_storage_container = storage_container<storage_container_impl<T> >;

typedef impl_storage_container<data_c<int, impl_storage_container> > c_storage_container;

int main()
{
    c_storage_container tmp;
    tmp.data.c=5;
    tmp.data.link=&tmp;
    return tmp.data.c;
}
```

Which results in following error (gcc 4.7):

```
test1.cpp:6:48: error: no type named 'ref' in 'impl_storage_container<data_c<int, impl_storage_container> > {aka class storage_container<storage_container_impl<data_c<int, impl_storage_container> > >}'
```

It works if I use `T *data` instead of `T data` (But I do not want that indirection), or if I do not use `storage_container_impl` and have `T data` directly in `storage_container`. Using `storage_container_impl` mixin-style does not solve the problem as well. As `container_ref` is a pointer, there also should be no reason why it does not work, e.g. because there is a loop in the template declaration. This is a minimized version of the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd guess that at the point where `data` is declared `data_c` is instantiated, which in turn refers to `storage_container`, which is not complete at that point yet. Clang doesn't accept it as well, which I take as indication that it's in fact illegal.

Comment: So ... your container should contain a single instance of a wrapper type, containing a single instance of the value type and a back pointer to the container. Is that really right?

Comment: Obvious question: have you measured that virtual polymorphism would indeed be too slow in your case?

Comment: @Philipp No I didn't, but I'm working with someone else's code and he chose the template route.
If this is illegal, I'll just save `link` as `void*` and cast, I think.

Comment: I can't quote the standard, but if Clang and GCC agree there's a change they're right :)
When I tried to formulate `data_c` using the "normal" CRTP (without a template template parameter), I think I encountered an endless type recursion. That might indicate that C++ actually doesn't allow this structure (although it's possible that it allows more type recursion with template template parameters, I know too little about them to say for sure).

Comment: "*I'll just save `link` as `void*` and cast*" No, please don't -- this completely defeats the purpose of using templates for type safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that it's not a perfect solution, but you can try to replace

```
typedef impl_storage_container<data_c<int, impl_storage_container> > c_storage_container;
```

with

```
typedef impl_storage_container<data_c<int, storage_container_impl> > c_storage_container;
```

It compiles and work. Otherwise you get endless type recursion.